# Why are not all messages from Docker run in Jenkins log?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am building Raspberry Pi images with Jenkins and Docker. I have a bash script which resizes the raspbian image and adds my applications. From most commands I get the output in Jenkins log but not from all. For example I don't see any echo messages.

The bash script is started from Jenkinsfile by the follwing command:

```
def image = docker.image("rpi-builder")
                image.inside("-v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static -v /dev:/dev2 --privileged=true --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --network jenkins_network")
                { 
                    sh 'bash /repo/MakeImage/mkImage.sh ${HOST_NAME} ${BACKUP_NAME} ${NODE_VERSION}'
                    sh "cp /rpi_image.img ${WORKSPACE}"
                    archiveArtifacts 'rpi_image.img'
                }
```

In the Jenkins log I can see for example the output from

```
unzip rpi_img.zip
```

But there is nothing from

```
echo "Step one"
```

If I run the script without Jenkins for example by

```
docker exec -it 135776076ae8b5ea73e6f9f8a559f1d38824d457bee4c1b2285399c636b95920 /bin/bash /repo/MakeImage/mkImage.sh iobpitest iobpi v10.23.1-armv6l
```

I can see the echo message in the output.

Why is it not in the Jenkins log? Have I to redirect it to somewhere?

Comment: Is it really necessary to start a new Bash in `sh 'bash ...'`?

Comment: I want to be sure that bash is used. I don’t know which shell would be used as default. Do you think it would work if I don’t start a new bash?

Comment: You can configure your shell in _Manage Jenkins_ → _System Configuration_ → _Configure System_ → _Shell_ → _Shell Interpreter Command_.

Comment: I configured bash as Shell Interpreter and called the script without starting a new bash. But this doesn't change anything. I still can't see any echo messages.